# .bash_logout or .zlogout isn't parsed when autostarting xserver directly after login on console

Tags: shell, login, profile, logout, startx

I made a line:

```
[[ -z $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -le 4 ]] && exec startx
```

(right out of the Arch Wiki) at the end of `.xinitrc` to start the Xserver right after login on console.

Whenever I'm ending the session, daemons started in `.xinitrc` will not be killed when logging out, regardless of using `bash` or `zsh`.

It seems as if `.bash_logout/.zlogout` are not being parsed, basically just holding:

```
kill -15 -1 &&
```

Anyone else having that problem and maybe a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`exec`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-exec) builtin replaces the shell by the specified program. After that point, the shell is no longer around to load `.*logout`.

In any case, the shell that runs `.xinitrc` is not a login shell, so it wouldn't run any `.*logout` file — but that shell is not where you would run `startx` anyway, it's a file that's loaded from `xinit` which is executed by `startx`.

If you want to run something after logging out of the graphical session, you need to keep the shell running and specify something to run after `startx`. Assuming that the `exec startx` line is in `.profile` or a similar file executed by your login shell, you need to keep the shell running while the X session is active, then `exit` (so as not to follow the GUI session by an interactive shell).

```
if [[ -z $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -le 4 ]]; then
  if startx; then
    # We just exited an X session.
    exit
    # If your login shell is bash, it runs ~/.logout at this point.
  else
    echo >&2 "The X session aborted with an error, dropping to a text shell"
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful! I had a look into `man exec` now, one just need to know where to look. I can't upvote right now because of a low reputation, this has been my first question here.

Comment: @Mono `exec` is a shell builtin, so you need to look in your shell's manual (e.g. [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-exec) — the basics are the same in all shells).

Comment: `@Gilles` Ah, alright. Found it in `man bash` and `man zshbuiltins` now. One just need to.. Thanks again :-) I tried the line without `exec`, just `&& xinit -- :0 -nolisten tcp vt$XDG_VTNR`, which worked, dropping me back to console when Xserver stops, regardless of reason. I will try your loop now, which provides easy logout.